# php5-ps no longer in Debian Jessie

Tags: debian

I try to install php5-ps in Jessie, there is no support anymore  ? - I must mention that in older Debian is working.

```
aptitude install php5-ps  
No candidate version found for php5-ps  
No candidate version found for php5-ps No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
```

In other words:

```
apt-get install php5-ps
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package php5-ps is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'php5-ps' has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 0):

You may install it via pecl and try to use.

```
apt-get install php5-dev make build-essential pslib-dev libgd-dev php5-gd
pecl install ps-1.3.7
echo "extension=ps.so" > /etc/php5/mods-available/ps.ini
php5enmod ps
```